# Mongoose. Use a constant in $or

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a query and would like to include access control:

```
  var q = { $and:
    [
      { $or: [
          isAdmin,    // does this use have access to all Resources?
                      // This pattern doesn't appear to work
          { isPublic: true },
          { createdBy: userId }
        ]
      },
      query
    ]
  };
  Resource.find(q).sort('-createdAt').limit(10)...
```

`isAdmin` can be true or false.  If false, then I'd like to do the other tests.  `query` is the rest of the query.

It's not working in mongoose 4.0.4.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please, share your schema too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found two ways to do this.  The best way is to not include the $or when isAdmin.  Kind of obvious really.

```
function findNewestResources(query, callback) {
  if (!isAdmin) {
    query = { $and:
      [
        { $or: [
            { isPublic: true },
            { createdBy: userId }
          ]
        },
        query
      ]
    };
  }
  Resource.find(query).sort('-createdAt').limit(10)
```

An alternate way was to use `$where`, but it does a table-scan, so that's no good.  The $where worked on 2.6.10, but not on 2.6.9.